# How to compile gedit LaTeX plugin?

Tags: compiling, gedit, latex

Because I'd like to use the Gedit LaTeX plugin that is unfortunately not available for Gedit 3.2 in the repositories, I want to compile it myself. The most recent version you can get on http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit-latex does support GNOME 3
's Gedit.

In the documentation it says:

> Due to a limitation on reading Settings, the plugin currently must be
>   installed in the same prefix as gedit. For instance if you are using
>   gedit 3 from your distribution, you need to do
>
> `./configure --prefix=/usr make sudo make install`
>
> If you are using a 64bit distribution, you also need to pass
>   `--libdir=/usr/lib64` to `./configure` script.

That's why I `cd`ed into the directory that contains the code, and tried to run `./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64`. Unfortunately, this does not work, giving the error message:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Having checked the folder, there indeed is no file `configure`, but only `configure.ac`. **What can I do to compile this plugin?**

Comment: just install this package -> `apt-get install autopoint` and execute autogen.sh again.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Library necessaries to build the configuration files

   ```
   sudo apt-get install intltool libtool
   ```
2. Dependency necessary to compile this plug-ins

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gedit-dev
   ```
3. Build the configuration file

   ```
   touch config.rpath
   ./autogen.sh
   ```
4. Configure and compile

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

**If you are using a 64bit distribution, you also need to pass `--libdir=/usr/lib64`
to `./configure script`.**

```
    ./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
```

**With a 64bit distribution, I also had to create two symbolic links, otherwise the plugin would not show up:**

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/gedit/plugins/latex.plugin /usr/lib/gedit/plugins/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/gedit/plugins/latex /usr/lib/gedit/plugins/
```

Comment: hhlp, thanks a lot! However, `touch config.rpath
./autogen.sh` gives an error, could you check my question again? I put the message there. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Whatever, now it works....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu Oneiric 64-bit, you have to download and extract this http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gedit-latex/3.2/gedit-latex-3.2.1.tar.bz2. The intltool and libgtk-dev packages are needed, so you have to install them

```
sudo apt-get install intltool libgtk-3-dev
```

Once you've done that, `cd` into the directory gedit-latex-3.2.1 you extracted and run

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
make
sudo make install
```

And everything should be fine.

P.S. The LaTeX plugin uses rubber by default, so if you are not changing the compilation tools that are already there you should install (or check if installed) the packages: rubber, python-poppler, python-glade2, python-enchant and texlive.

Comment: package `libgtk-dev` doesn't exit in any ubuntu version -> http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgtk-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: It was libgtk-3-dev, I didn't notice the typo, but I already changed it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work because you're missing the step `touch config.rpath
./autogen.sh`. But nevermind, because that one doesn't work either ;).

Comment: I tried it like described (using and extracting the package in the link I provided) and everithing worked. Well, good luck anyway! :)